# graph api query with $filter operator (STARTS WITH and NOT)

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm working on a Graph API query where I am trying to get Groups based on certain conditions. Here is the query below

with **'ConsistencyLevel': 'eventual'** header

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$filter=startswith(displayName , 'xyz') and NOT(groupTypes/any(c:c+eq+'Unified')) and securityEnabled eq false and mailEnabled eq true&$select=displayName,mail
```

***Property 'groupTypes' does not exist as a declared property or extension property.***

How would I combine **STARTS WITH** and **NOT** operator and pass it in $filter?

Comment: Can you try `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$count=true&$filter=startswith(displayName, 'test') and not groupTypes/any(c:c eq 'Unified') and securityEnabled eq false and mailEnabled eq true&$select=displayName,mail` query. Check [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/TxoDWQE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note** that: To query groups based on certain conditions, you need to make use of '**groups**' endpoint instead of '**users**'.

- The  ***groupTypes***  property is property is applicable to groups, not users.

When I executed the same query as you, got the **same error**:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$filter=startswith(displayName , 'test') and NOT(groupTypes/any(c:c+eq+'Unified')) and securityEnabled eq false and mailEnabled eq true&$select=displayName,mail

ConsistencyLevel: Eventual
```

[image]

Hence, **to resolve the error** make use of groups endpoint:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$count=true&$filter=startswith(displayName, 'test') and not groupTypes/any(c:c eq 'Unified') and securityEnabled eq false and mailEnabled eq true&$select=displayName,mail

ConsistencyLevel: Eventual
```

[image]

***Output:***

```json
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups(displayName,mail)",
"@odata.count": 1,
"value": [
{
"displayName": "Testgroup",
"mail": "samplegroup@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
}
]
}
```